# Resources getting created using Terraform but still errors out?

Tags: azure, terraform

I am trying to create few Azure resources using TerraForm

- Resource Group
- Role Definition
- Storage Account
- Role Assignment

I have added resource dependencies to not run the code in parallel also added a sleep time to allow the resource to be created, but still, the code errors out. It works for the first time but after you destroy and create again, it throws an error and stops the execution, it saying Role_definition_name does not exist, but if you check the console it has been created by the same code only.

What can be done here, if the role_definition is erroring but still creating the role, I need that error should not stop the execution of the program.

Here's my code, it's dependent on resource group which is successfully created

```
provider "azurerm" {
 features {}
}

 resource "azurerm_role_definition" "test" {

 depends_on  = [azurerm_resource_group.test]

 name        = "any-random_string"
 scope       = "/subscriptions/xxxxx/resourceGroups/abcde"
 description = "Custom role created via Terraform"


 permissions {
actions     = [

"Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/resourceGroups/read",


]
not_actions = []
 }

 assignable_scopes = [
"/subscriptions/xxxxx/resourceGroups/abcde"
 ]



provisioner "local-exec" {
command = "sleep 30"
 }


}
```

Comment: Do you have a code to show? Also what is the exact error that you are getting?

Comment: @Marcin yes I have just updated

Comment: Can you share the whole Terraform code? The error seems caused by other resources' creation after the role definition.